# ReactDOM Hello World

Tags: reactjs, dom

struggling with this simple example of React for 3 hours :C . The "mainDiv" works fine as it should, but i see no HELLO WORLD there.
here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>REACT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv" class="divstyle"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        let A = <div className="HW">HELLO WORLD!</div>;
        let B = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
        reactDOM.render(A,B);

    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

======================= CSS =======================

```
.divstyle {
text-align: center;
background-color: #4285F4;
color: white;
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 30px;
```

}

```
.HW {
text-align: center;
color: white;
```

}

Comment: i missed </html> at the end while pasting the code here

Comment: You should probably include the React scripts _before_ the actual React code in the HTML. So that Babel is ready when JSX script execute. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Jayce444 i moved it above the first script and even in head tag, didnt work. 
nope no errors at all, it just doesnt work

Comment: Why did you do this directly in the <html/>? And why not make a component?

Comment: @zahrazamani its the first exercise in the tutorials, i don't know anything about components yet  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's some minor tweaks I made to get it working.

1. Put loading of Babel/React libs in the head tag
2. Use current, official Babel CDN, your one was giving me some issues in Chrome
3. Looks like you had a typo, you had `reactDOM` instead of `ReactDOM`

I tried this and it worked just fine:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>REACT</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv" class="divstyle"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        let A = <div className="HW">HELLO WORLD!</div>;
        let B = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
        ReactDOM.render(A,B);

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The Babel was the issue :) tyvm

Answer (score 0):

in file public/index.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>REACT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="root"></div> 
       
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

in file index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Index extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="HW">HELLO WORLD!</div>;
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```